# SSH Login fails while executing a backup bash script to commit to Stash

Tags: linux, git, bash, authentication, ssh

(I am very  new to git and version control. ) I have several bash scripts that perform nightly backups- I also have a cronjob already set up,. Executing a single script at a time also requires the password even though I have tried my best to enable the scripts to perform ssh authentication but I keep getting prompted for my stash password when they execute(I have looked at several online resources but I think I keep going around in circles- not reaching anywhere close to the solution), if I could get my scripts to execute via ssh authentication then I can  go ahead and run the cron job successfully.

I have already created the public - private key pair and my public key has been added to the Stash Project.

A ssh -v 'username'@'server' gives the following output :

```
`OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to dbstore1 [10.4.2.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/<myusername>/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<myusername>/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/<myusername>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'dbstore1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<myusername>/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<myusername>/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/<myusername>/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8

`
```

So looking at the above result- the authentication using the SSH public key is successful for my user account, right?

Now, the problem comes  in when i execute the schema backup script - sudo ./script.sh

It keeps asking me for my (stash) password when it is about to commit/push. Also, I noticed that when I supply the password and there is a successful commit on Stash - the author is displayed as 'root'.

So my SSH public key is set up for MY user account but the commits are made from root - Could this be a cause of why ssh login doesn't work for me ?

Comment: Yes. That is the cause. Why are you running that script as root in the first place?

Comment: That is how I run all the scripts (and used to on svn as well , we are migrating from svn to git.). I have limited privileges.   Is there any way around this?

Comment: You have limited privileges to what? What about your scripts requires both elevated privs on the local machine *and* commit privs on the server? That's an unfortunate mix. I would split the concerns if at all possible (and drop the need for root entirely if possible). Also if you are using the git repository to backup the repositories own  contents daily (via tag or whatnot) that's ... slightly odd and quite possibly not necessary (but that's an entirely different issue).

Comment: If you *absolutely* must keep things as-is then you want to modify the script to use `su`/`sudo` to run the git commit/etc. as your original user and/or (though this is horrifically worse) set up the root user with your git configuration and ssh keys.

Comment: Okay so I am now able to run the scripts without using sudo , but I still get asked for my stash password. When I supplied my stash password, the commit made is labelled by  my user name and not root. So you think I will be better off by creating a separate generic user account for the backups? Is there any way in Stash to store password? This ssh thing is going way over my head now. I have tried changing the remote origin url from https to ssh and then back again to https; still  no change

Comment: ssh keys likely only work for `ssh` connections to stash. If you are using that and have your user's keys configured for your account in stash and are running the script as your user then the commits should show up as you and you shouldn't need your password (assuming the successful key use as indicated in the output above).